# How to escape from a rear headlock while held at gunpoint?

Tags: self-defense, firearms

[image]

Let's say I came across this kind of situation. What do I do?

Answer (score 9):

You comply with whatever you are being asked to do.

You are not going to escape that without being shot but on the other hand you have not been shot yet.  That means that your captor wants you alive at least for now.  So do what they say and stay alert for a better time to try to escape.

Answer (score 2):

One possible option, if you just want to avoid being a hostage, is to make yourself an inconvenient hostage. Faint (or fake doing so) when the gun isn't pointed at your head. Vomit in fear. Lose control of your bowels. Unless you're the only option, the criminal isn't going to want to drag dead weight along, or deal with the smell. And most hostage takers really don't want to shoot someone. They want to get away, preferably with their loot.

Comment: Yes, I have read the defecating on oneself can be an affective defense.  I imagine diarrhea is even better.  So for those with IBS, ulcerative colitis, or the like, your silver lining is finally here!

Answer (score 1):

There are techniques to do so, and why not learn them, but understand the math on not getting shot is very pessimistic, such that if you try to apply them in real life, you almost certainly get shot.

The movies show such techniques routinely, and it's a major part of serious "gun fu" fight choreography, but remember they're doing things like disassembling a loaded pistol held by the opponent, and so alway should be taken with a grain of salt.

If I was a significantly more proficient grappler than the assailant, and assumed they were going to kill me anyway, I would wait until the muzzle is off target and move in a manner so as to control their wrist, keeping the muzzle off-target, and removing it from their hand by whatever method was most expedient, but **I'd still assume I was going to die.**

Answer (score -1):

Those who stay cool, calm, and collective are the ones who prevail in situations like this. Obviously easier said than done, but it is the only option.